# Pledge reminder email links to admin page instead of public

Tags: joomla, civipledge

I manually ran the pledge process job but the link in the email is pointing to an administrator page and not a public page, as shown below:

http://sflcon.cfcfflusa.net/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1&cid=2&pledgeId=1&cs=3fe71009786503d09c4ca1aa65d29aa5_1522072223_168

Please let me know how to correct this so that those receiving the emails can access the link.

Ron

civicrm 4.7.29
joomla 3.8.6